# Scala tuple of collections instead of collection of tuples

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-collections

In one invocation to `map` we construct a collection of tuples, for instance like this,

```
val a = (1 to 5).map { x => (x, x*10) }
a: Vector((1,10), (2,20), (3,30), (4,40), (5,50))
```

and then we extract the first and second elements into two separate, immutable collections

```
val b1 = a.map {_._1}
b1: Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val b2 = a.map {_._2}
b2: Vector(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

How to obtain `b1` and `b2` by iterating over the initial collection once only,

```
val (b1,b2) = (1 to 5).map { x => /* ??? */ }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `unzip`:

```
scala> (1 to 5).unzip { x => x -> x * 3 }
res0: (Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),Vector(3, 6, 9, 12, 15))
```

Comment: Note this is the same as: 

    (1 to 5).unzip{ x => (x, x * 3)}

Answer (score 1):

Note that Ionuț G. Stan's answer is the same as:

```
(1 to 5).unzip{ x => (x, x * 3)}
```

which makes how to get *triples* of collections back even clearer:

```
(1 to 5).unzip3{ x => (x, x * 3, x * 10)}
```